# String.substring(i,j) method gets blank spaces rather than actual characters

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, substring

The code below is the entire program so far (just to avoid any missing pieces.

The issue I'm having is that I'm trying use the .substring(int,int) method to pull two characters from the given string and write the two characters pulled into a separate array. The problem is that every character pulled from the string using .substring() is a blank space. There are no letters pulled at all. I tested the function using a simple print method and it went to show that printing `sentences.get(i).substring(j,j++)` only prints blank spaces. It's populating my arrays with those empty spaces.

Any clue as to what could be causing this? My compiler isn't giving me any errors or warnings whatsoever.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JacSim {

public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner userScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter the filename for your input file (with extension).");
    String fileName = userScanner.nextLine();

    File file = new File(fileName);

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner( new FileInputStream(file));

    List<String> sentences = new ArrayList();

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String sentence = scanner.nextLine();
        sentences.add(sentence);
    }

    System.out.println("Input Sentences:\n");

    for(int i=0;i<sentences.size();i++) {
        System.out.println(i + " : " + sentences.get(i));
    }

    List<List<String>> shingles = new ArrayList();

    sentences.stream().forEach((String _item) -> {
        shingles.add(new ArrayList());
    });

    System.out.println("\nSorted Shingle Arrays:\n");

    shinglesMethod(shingles, sentences);
}

private static List shinglesMethod(List<List<String>> shingles, List<String> sentences) {

    for (int i=0;i<sentences.size();i++) {
        for(int j=0;j++<sentences.get(i).length();j++) {
            shingles.get(i).add(sentences.get(i).substring(j,j++));
        }
        showList( i, shingles.get(i) );
    }
    return shingles;
}

private static void showList( int n, List List ) {
    System.out.print(n + " : ");
    List.stream().forEach((o) -> {
        System.out.print( o + " " );
    });
    System.out.println();
}
```

The chunk of code to pay attention to is

```
for (int i=0;i<sentences.size();i++) {
        for(int j=0;j++<sentences.get(i).length();j++) {
            shingles.get(i).add(sentences.get(i).substring(j,j++));
        }
        showList( i, shingles.get(i) );
    }
```

Forgot to clarify that the scanner is reading in the words properly and that each string is read as expected. The only issue I'm finding is with the .substring() method.

Comment: Yeah I've been going over it for the past hour thinking I'm missing something. It seems like the issue may lie in the ++j not j++ suggested by Louis and lared.

Comment: On further reflection, it's not really `++j` you want, it's `j+1` pretty much everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be rooted in confusion about what `++` does.  `j++` returns the value of `j` and *afterwards* increments `j`.

`.substring(j,j++)` will always return the empty string, because it increments `j` after getting a substring between j inclusive and j exclusive.  `substring(j, j + 1)` would probably be more what you want.

You also need to use `j + 1 < sentences.get(i).length()`, instead of `j++`, because you're changing the value of `j` as you're trying to check it, which is almost certainly not what you want.  The only place `j++` should be mentioned would be in the update statement in the for loop.

Comment: Your implementation worked with a few adjustments. I had been trying to grab every other character with my original .substring() method but I was actually trying to do something else. Since your suggestion helped the most I'll provide you the answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Now to sort them in lexicographical order... -.-

Comment: substring(j, j + 1) will pull out only one character at a time. I think the OP wants to pull out two characters at a time.

Answer (score 0):

`j++` uses the value of `j` and then increments the value of `j`. So your code is equivalent to `substring(j,j)`. Also, when you write `x.substring(i,j)`, the substring begins at `i` and extends to the character at `j - 1`.

Use `substring(j,j+2)` instead and change the condition of your inner while loop to `j<sentences.get(i).length() - 2`.